# Change a page using app-route and paper-icon-button

Tags: polymer-2.x

Based on the [starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) I have created a new app. I would like to link the different pages to a set of icons in the app-toolbar.

I got it working with:

```
    <a href="/main-stream">
      <paper-icon-button icon="icons:view-stream"></paper-icon-button>
    </a>
```

But I think I am missing something here. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

in your app-Component you have a variable called `page`. This variable indicates the current view that is shown. To modify its value you can use the iron-selector like in the demo app.

```
<iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
  <a name="view1" href="[[rootPath]]view1">View One</a>
  <a name="view2" href="[[rootPath]]view2">View Two</a>
  <a name="view3" href="[[rootPath]]view3">View Three</a>
</iron-selector>
```

Copied from:https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/src/my-app.html